# Pisa 150cc scooter

Tags: starting, scooter

My scooter doesnt want to start anymore, i bought a new plug and checked the carburetor and tried to start it but it seems like my battery has no power, so I charged it but it still did the same thing what should I do.

Comment: Is there a starter motor on this scooter? I'm assuming there is, as it has a battery. One of the first thing to observe is whether the starter motor is rotating. Did you hear the starter rotate? If you heard, it's probably not the battery; if you didn't hear, and don't hear even after recharging the battery, why did you purchase a new plug and check the carburetor?

Comment: Have you checked the fuel?